# Error when I try to use nonlinsolve to solve a system of nonlinear equations

Tags: python, sympy

I'm trying to use SymPy, which I've never done before, to solve a system of nonlinear equations, but I can't get it to work.

Here is what I have tried:

```
from sympy import *

a, b, c, d, e, f, x, y, z, g0, g1, g2 = symbols('a:f x:z g:3')
system = [(a * (x - y*z))/(b * (1 - z**2)) - g1,
(a * (y - x*z))/(c * (1 - z**2)) - g2,
f - d * (a * (x - y*z))/(b * (1 - z**2)) - e * (a * (y - x*z))/(c * (1 - z**2)) - g0]
nonlinsolve(system, [x, y, z])
```

What I want are the values of x, y and z in terms of the other symbols that solve the system. But I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/phl43/Desktop/test.py", line 7, in <module>
    nonlinsolve(system, [x, y, z])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sympy/solvers/solveset.py", line 3053, in nonlinsolve
    res = _handle_positive_dimensional(polys, symbols, denominators)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sympy/solvers/solveset.py", line 2801, in _handle_positive_dimensional
    denominators)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sympy/solvers/solveset.py", line 2719, in substitution
    old_result, solveset_real)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sympy/solvers/solveset.py", line 2708, in _solve_using_known_values
    result.remove(res)
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

Any idea how to make this work?

Comment: According to [this open issue](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/15422) there might be a bug in the library cause this issue.

Comment: Thanks, I saw this open issue earlier, so I was afraid it might be a bug, but since I have never used this library before I was hoping that I had done something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

See what you can learn by solving the system manually without checking:

```
>>> r = solve(system, dict=True, manual=True, check=False)
>>> r
[{x: -y, z: -1}, {x: y, z: 1}, {x: (b*g1 + c*g2*z)/a, y: (b*g1*z + c*g2)/a}]
```

The first two solutions are not going to work because that would lead to division by 0. The last solution sets the first two equations to 0 while the last solution satisfies the first two equations but these make the last expression independent of z:

```
>>> [simplify(i.subs(r[-1])) for i in r]
[0, 0, -d*g1 - e*g2 + f - g0]
```

So `z` can be anything provided that `g0 = f -d*g1 - e*g2`. It is an ill-posed set of equations for solving for x, y, and z.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful, but shouldn't nonlinsolve have returned some kind of message indicating the set of equations was ill-posed instead of crashing?

Comment: Yes. And adding `and res` to (now) line 3048 of solveset.py gives the following for your system: `{(-(-b*g1 - c*g2*z)/a, (b*g1*z + c*g2)/a, z), ((b*g1 + c*g2*z)/a,
(b*g1*z + c*g2)/a, z), (-(-a*y*z + b*g1*z**2 - b*g1)/a, y, z), ((a*y*z
- b*g1*z**2 + b*g1)/a, y, z)}`. So the issue #15422 is still the culprit.